# Where can I find *newer* looking glyphs for TBitBtn?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 2007, and I am looking for some newer looking glyphs to add to my TBitBtns. Honestly, I'd love something that looks more like the [Tango Desktop](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) or KDE4, when it comes to the glyphs.

If I can't find anything else, I'll just use the Tango icons, and convert them to *.pcx or *.bmp.

However, I'm curious if anyone knows of some components that already include this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Primarily, I am looking for glyphs to add to buttons (TBitBtn specifically).

Comment: What kind of "glyphs" are you searching for? Icons? Characters? Icons representing Characters?

Comment: Icons for buttons. Something like cleaner looking red x's, and cleaner looking green checks, etc.

Comment: I don't think that "where to find a 16x16 or 24x24 or 32x32 or 48x48 bitmap or png file" is really a programming question. however I do think it's useful to programmers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [famfamfam.com](http://famfamfam.com/lab/icons/). The collections are nice, but some of them are in PNG-format, so you still have to convert the images.

Comment: Or upgrade to Delphi 2009 which can handle the PNG images natively.

Answer (score 5):

D2006 and above include some new icons located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Images or whatever your path, but you can get a complete list with much nicer icons and different sizes from both [glyFX](http://www.glyfx.com) and [Glyfz](http://www.glyfz.com)

Comment: GlyFX make some very nice icons. We've used them for a number of years and the collections just keep getting better

Answer (score 4):

You have a pretty nice set of components on your harddrive:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Images\GlyFX

Answer (score 3):

We have recently bought the complete icon set from [Icon Experience](http://www.iconexperience.com/) to use in all our applications. Before that, I have spend a lot of time in searching for good looking free icon packs, but couldn't find any. Icon Experience comes with a handy search program and an editor so you can easily modify all icons (add small add/delete/search overlays etc).

For us, it was a god investment ($379), but I don't know your budget.

By the way, all icons come in png/ico/bmp format and a conversion utility.

Answer (score 3):

You can find more free icons, in multiple formats and sizes at:

- http://www.iconlet.com/
- http://www.iconfinder.net/
- http://www.iconlook.com/

Answer (score 2):

I use [Axialis Icon Workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) and some of its icon packs. It is a commercial program with a free trial, and it has plugin icon packs which can be purchased separately.

For commercial use, with royalty-free redistribution rights, I find it effective as a professional solution. If you are doing casual personal development then the free site you accepted looks fine to me.

The Glyfx icons that come with Delphi versions since 2009, are also nicer than the old Delphi 5 era bitmaps, but not enough for most people, thus my suggestion.

Comment: +1 I'm a big fan of their Pure Flat icon sets -- very modern and clear.

Answer (score 2):

3,570 16x16 icons at http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/ Free use by attribution, or purchase a license.

Answer (score 0):

I've licensed icons from www.icons-icons.com in the past. They're good looking and affordable.
http://www.icons-icons.com/index.php